# How to find the row where a value is higher than a number and plot its coordinate?

Tags: matlab

If I have this matrix M:

```
M =[0   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90
5   0.284491788  0.312419395 0.327207952 0.334946026 0.339755602 0.342395525 0.344233852 0.345327586 0.346104243 0.34657095  0.346777584 0.346927215 0.347005593 0.347080409 0.347137411 0.347158787 0.347180163 0.347190851
10  0.300057002 0.3301507   0.34627525  0.354729417 0.359959386 0.362862945 0.364882967 0.366055079 0.366878051 0.367362571 0.367583455 0.367754462 0.367839966 0.367925469 0.367986034 0.36800741  0.368028786 0.368039474
15  0.315522463 0.348113577 0.365474367 0.374605437 0.380323489 0.383497809 0.385653212 0.386942891 0.387840678 0.388360825 0.388606648 0.388816844 0.388920161 0.38901279  0.389076918 0.389098293 0.389119669 0.389130357
20  0.331119741 0.366108518 0.384972746 0.39493035  0.401193487 0.404656382 0.406986355 0.408386476 0.409366205 0.409914853 0.410192739 0.410417186 0.410527628 0.410627383 0.41069151  0.410716449 0.410737825 0.410748513
25  0.347347608 0.384858741 0.405034023 0.415832413 0.422576508 0.42631729  0.428864584 0.430410773 0.431440379 0.432053155 0.432352417 0.432580427 0.432708682 0.432811999 0.432883252 0.432908191 0.432929566 0.432940254
30  0.362410488 0.40227297  0.423944565 0.435523175 0.442766041 0.44679896  0.449577826 0.451245146 0.452324629 0.452990844 0.453318608 0.453553743 0.453681998 0.453796003 0.453870818 0.453895757 0.453924258 0.453934946
35  0.376946097 0.419277495 0.442399088 0.454836296 0.462656311 0.466949304 0.469924116 0.47170544  0.472877552 0.473575831 0.473928533 0.474181481 0.474316862 0.474430867 0.474509245 0.474537746 0.474566247 0.474576935
40  0.391574335 0.436360398 0.460981866 0.47432755  0.482721151 0.487341907 0.490491289 0.492386619 0.493615733 0.494395953 0.494762906 0.495019416 0.495179736 0.495304428 0.495389932 0.495418433 0.495446934 0.495464748
45  0.406220385 0.453646371 0.479924472 0.494110941 0.503035377 0.507941145 0.511293598 0.513320745 0.514656739 0.515483273 0.515885853 0.516167302 0.516334747 0.516459439 0.516552068 0.516580569 0.516609071 0.516626884
50  0.420232285 0.470177064 0.497937226 0.513060672 0.522508818 0.527735224 0.531251559 0.533396273 0.534810645 0.53569062  0.536107449 0.536399587 0.53659197  0.53672735  0.536819979 0.536848481 0.536876982 0.536894795
55  0.434824896 0.487441662 0.516933272 0.533000819 0.542951299 0.548448466 0.552196373 0.554465781 0.555937155 0.556867006 0.557319463 0.557640101 0.557850297 0.557992803 0.558085432 0.558113934 0.558142435 0.558160248
60  0.448729916 0.504029356 0.535195411 0.552171435 0.562738252 0.568559621 0.572517724 0.57491895  0.576468702 0.577441305 0.5779187   0.578253589 0.578470911 0.578620542 0.578713171 0.578741672 0.578770174 0.578787987
65  0.462649186 0.520620613 0.553350672 0.571245858 0.582375574 0.588524707 0.592693007 0.595272365 0.59689337  0.597926538 0.598435997 0.598788699 0.599013146 0.59916634  0.599262532 0.599291033 0.599319534 0.599337347
70  0.475371406 0.535943568 0.57038726  0.589212298 0.600933414 0.607378246 0.611746054 0.614475044 0.61617799  0.617257473 0.61779187  0.618158823 0.618390395 0.618550714 0.618650468 0.61869322  0.618721721 0.618739535
75  0.488100752 0.551262959 0.587185151 0.606875913 0.619220492 0.625964587 0.630610282 0.633467526 0.635277352 0.636410275 0.636973173 0.637343689 0.637585949 0.637756956 0.637860273 0.63791015  0.637938651 0.637956464
80  0.499832555 0.565477929 0.602782429 0.623342477 0.636278457 0.643282625 0.648145641 0.651113328 0.653005095 0.654216395 0.654804232 0.655188999 0.655452635 0.65563433  0.655741209 0.655794649 0.65582315  0.655844526
85  0.511222345 0.579325947 0.618169511 0.639670099 0.653136913 0.660465282 0.665520681 0.668634437 0.670593894 0.671844383 0.67247141  0.672877552 0.673148313 0.673340696 0.673451138 0.673504578 0.673533079 0.673554455
90  0.522344936 0.592785635 0.632936692 0.655249564 0.669208023 0.676910471 0.682186754 0.685414514 0.687487976 0.688788343 0.689450996 0.689864263 0.69014215  0.690348783 0.690459225 0.690512665 0.690541166 0.690566105];
```

we are going to plot only [,1] and [1,] values:
the idea is to find the rows of the columns from 2 to 19 (i,2:19) where the value is higher than 0.4 and plot the the rows which match the condition agains its respective column.

The values to select the rows would be like:

[image: selected rows]

The results would be like:

```
rows = [45 30 25 25 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20];
col = [5:5:90];

plot (rows, col);
```

Comment: start with: [j,i]=find(M>0.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each column is in ascending sorted order that you see in your matrix, you can threshold the matrix beyond 0.4, then find the first index in each column that surpasses this threshold.  You can use the [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function in MATLAB to help you do that.  You can thus locate the row location that surpasses this threshold for each column, skipping the first column and we also skip the first row.  You can then use this to index into the first row and finally plot your data.  Note that you'll have to offset your indices by 1 because we skipped the first row, first column:

```
[~,ind] = max(M(2:end,2:end) > 0.4, [], 1);
rows = M(1, ind + 1);
```

With your example, we thus get:

```
>> format compact
>> rows
ans =
    45    30    25    25    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20    20
```

This agrees with your expected result.

Comment: Yes, thats it.. Thanks! now I can go deeper and learn about indexes!

Comment: @PhilDuran No problem at all.  A pretty fun exercise.  BTW, let me know if you need any more help. If you don't, it's customary to [accept the answer that helped you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're ready.  Until then, good luck!